# React typescript build cannot refer absolute path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, npm-build

I am publishing a react library which is written in typescript. And it is transpiled into
Javascript in the build. Inside typescript I am using `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json` and referring absolute path as follows

```
import CollabsibleMenu from 'components/collapsibleMenu';
```

It works well inside typescript but after I build it and try to use the package in another project it throws error

```
error - ./node_modules/aaarc-react/dist/components/verticalMenu/index.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/collapsibleMenu'
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["ES5", "ES2015", "ES2016", "DOM", "ESNext"],
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src"
    ],

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

And this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "aaarc-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.39",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "grommet": "^2.24.0",
    "grommet-icons": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rm -rf dist/ && tsc && cp tsconfig.json dist/jsconfig.json",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25"
  }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.js"]
```